# Org-mode not exporting to HTML file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a strange problem, when I run C-c C-e b, the file is not generated, but Emacs opens a file in browser. After the export it says:

> HTML export done, pushed to kill ring and clipboard

On top of that, there is not a single error message in *Messages* buffer. I've checked my Org-mode version (for mixed mode) and it should be ok, it shows:

> Org-mode version 7.9.3f (release_7.9.3f-17-g7524ef @
>   /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/org/)

However, if I run export to temporary buffer, it works as expected, I can save it to file and the export is done correctly.

Other types of export work, for example export to ODT and LaTeX works completely OK.

Comment: Difficult to help you with so few détails (no error msgs, in particular)... Can you upgrade to Org 8?  You can use the MELPA version for ease of installation...

Comment: Now it works, I've installed a 8.2 version and everything works as expected :)